# Manually trigger an ENTER key press event on wxTextCtrl in wxWidgets for C++?

Tags: c++, user-interface, events, wxwidgets, wxtextctrl

I have this text control:

```
FTextCtrl = new wxTextCtrl(parent, wxID_ANY, _("Text"), wxPoint(20, 20), wxDefaultSize, wxTE_CENTRE | wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_TC"));
FTextCtrl->Connect(wxEVT_CHAR, (wxObjectEventFunction)OnTextCharEvnt, NULL, this);
```

This function `OnTextCharEvnt` gets called whenever an <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed on the text control.

How can I manually trigger this event (when my text cursor is inside the text control) and call this function `OnTextCharEvnt` using the same?

Comment: Why not simply call `OnTextCharEvnt` directly? Or better, move its code to a separate function that both `OnTextCharEvnt` and You can call when needed.

Comment: Yeah ok! but how do I call this function with EVENT wxEVTCHAR. How do I call this function explicitly with that event

Comment: you are missing the point. You don't need to simulate input, you can just call your own function directly when you need it.

Comment: But calling this function directly `OnTextCharEvnt()` gives me error, like one argument required

Comment: obviously, since events have arguments to describe the events. But if you write a separate function, you don't have to give it any arguments if you don't need to, eg: `void OnTextCharEvnt(wxKeyEvent& event) { if (event.GetKeyCode() == WXK_RETURN) doSomething(); }` where `doSomething()` is the new function that you can call anywhere else you need it.

Comment: But if this is too above your current skill level, then have a look at the text control's [`EmulateKeyPress()`](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_text_ctrl.html#aac3e7f2124aafd67df6f6efbc285a40b) method instead.

Comment: I got it what you said and I after some research I did using the same way

Answer (score 0):

I use `EVT_TEXT_ENTER` It works ;

sample.h

```
enum{
 TEXT_FTextCtrl
}
```

sample.cpp

```
FTextCtrl = new wxTextCtrl(parent, TEXT_FTextCtrl, wxT("Text"), wxPoint(20, 20), wxDefaultSize, wxTE_CENTRE | wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_TC"));

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(Sample, wxFrame)
EVT_TEXT_ENTER(TEXT_FTextCtrl, Sample::OnTextCharEvnt)
END_EVENT_TABLE()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to trigger any events to call your own function -- just call it directly instead. Calling the event handler directly is awkward and not recommended, but this is a trivial solution avoiding it -- just have a normal function that you can call both from that event handler and directly:

```cpp
void Sample::OnTextCharEvnt(wxCommandEvent& event) { DoHandleCharEvent(event.GetUnicodeKey()); }

void Sample::DoHandleCharEvent(wchar_t key) { ... your actual code for handling it ... }

void Sample::SomeOtherFunction() { DoHandleEnter(); }
```

If you used the recommended `Bind()` function rather than old `Connect()`, you could even avoid having the trivial `OnTextCharEvnt()` entirely by using a lambda instead, e.g.:

```cpp
FTextCtrl->Bind(wxEVT_CHAR, [](wxCommandEvent& event) {
    DoHandleCharEvent(event.GetUnicodeKey());
});
```

All this ignores the fact that you should *not* be using `wxEVT_CHAR` with `wxTextCtrl` in the first place, but should handle either `wxEVT_TEXT` or `wxEVT_TEXT_ENTER` or both of them, instead of lower level char events (that won't get triggered at all if the user pastes something in the control, for example).